# RestTemplate | Reading unknown ENUM values as default value

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, resttemplate

I'm using `org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.9.RELEASE` and have a plain (not customized) `RestTemplate` class object I use to send a *POST* request by utilizing the *EXCHANGE* method. I want to allow it desirialize unknown *ENUM* values from the **response** to their default value (as set using `@JsonEnumDefaultValue`) instead of failing the whole operation. I've searched and didn't find any easy way to do it, can you give me some help with that? Thanks!

```
@Service
@CommonsLog
public class TMServerExternalApiRepositoryImpl implements TMServerExternalApiRepository {
    private final RestTemplate restRelay;
    private TeleMessageProperties tmUrls;

    @Autowired
    public TMServerExternalApiRepositoryImpl(RestTemplate restTemplate, TeleMessageProperties tmProperties) {
        this.restRelay = restTemplate;
        this.tmUrls = tmProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public VnvUsersSearchResult getUsersByPhone(String to, String from) {
        log.info(String.format("Trying to get users with telephones to: [%s], from: [%s] ", to, from));
        return sendRequest(new VnvUserSearchParams(from, to), VnvUsersSearchResult.class, tmUrls.getGetUserByPhoneUrl()).getBody();
    }

    //the actual post
    private <T, K> ResponseEntity<T> sendRequest(K content, Class<T> returnTypeClass, String url) throws HttpClientErrorException {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        HttpEntity<K> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(content, httpHeaders);

        return restRelay.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, returnTypeClass);
    }
}
```

This is the exception I am getting now:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class voiceAndVideo.services.VnvUsersSearchResult] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `voiceAndVideo.Util.VNVDevice$Type` from String "BAD_VALUE": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [MOBILE, ...]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `voiceAndVideo.Util.VNVDevice$Type` from String "BAD_VALUE": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [MOBILE, ...]
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 261] (through reference chain: voiceAndVideo.services.VnvUsersSearchResult["userFrom"]->voiceAndVideo.Util.VNVUser["devices"]->java.util.ArrayList[2]->voiceAndVideo.Util.VNVDevice["type"])
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
```

Classes:

```
public class VnvUsersSearchResult {
    private VNVUser userFrom;
    ...
}

public class VNVUser {
    ...
    protected List<VNVDevice> devices;
    ...
}

public class VNVDevice {
    public Type type;
    String mobile;

    public enum Type {
        @JsonEnumDefaultValue
        UNKNOWN(0),
        MOBILE(10),
        BUSINESS_PHONE(20),
        ...

        int ID;

        Type(int i) {
            this.ID = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of  `returnTypeClass ` and please post the specific exception message you are receiving?

Comment: @ShababbKarim - I've added the exception message.

Comment: I understand the rest template method you are using, I was asking for `VnvUsersSearchResult ` class definition.

Comment: @ShababbKarim Added this one too. VnvUsersSearchResult contains several fields of VNVUser and other strings and booleans, VNVUser contains strings, list of VNVDevice and booleans, VNVDevice is the ENUM that has been giving me trouble.

Comment: @ShababbKarim For instance, if I'm getting BAD_VALUE (which is not declared in VNVDevice) in the response, this exception is thrown. I would like to normalized it to UNKNOWN and maybe print a warning log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using JsonCreator placed in the ENUM class.

```
@JsonCreator
    public static Type getByValue(String t) {
        return Arrays.stream(Type.values())
                .filter(a -> a.name().equals(t)).findFirst().orElse(Type.UNKNOWN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to configure a custom `ObjectMapper` to the `RestTemplate` that you are using. You need to enable [this feature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE) on the `ObjectMapper`. ***Please make sure you are using fasterxml as the package for all these***.

In order to configure one, create a JavaConfig file like this:

```
@Bean
public RestOperations restOperations() {
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    
    rest.getMessageConverters().add(0, mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    return rest;
}

@Bean
public MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(myObjectMapper());
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper myObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // This where you enable default enum feature
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature. READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE, true);

    return objectMapper;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I post the original ENUM value (before it was changed to default) to the logs?

Comment: You can [register an interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33484957/5223309) in your rest template. Another easy solution is just get the raw response as string, log it and then use your Object mapper to deserialize.